# Calculate average from a power spectrum

Tags: fft, python, power-spectral-density

I want to calculate the **average of a power spectrum** in the complete frequency range. I have done a stft and want to calculate power in dB and then the average. Please let me know from the code below if my understanding is correct and how to calculate the average of the power spectrum.

```
y, sr = librosa.load('Noise Recorder.wav',sr=None,duration=2) 
n_fft = 8192
S = librosa.stft(y=y,n_fft=n_fft,win_length=n_fft,hop_length=n_fft,window='hann')     # Short FFT
F = librosa.fft_frequencies(sr=sr, n_fft=n_fft) # Frequency components
Abs = np.abs(S)  # Same as mag, phase = librosa.magphase(S)
Abs_avg = np.mean(Abs, axis=1)
Power_avg =librosa.power_to_db(Abs_mean**2) # dB
Scale_dB = 86.85    # Scaling factor

Power_Scaled_dB = Power_avg + Scale_dB  #Plot #Max:114dB at 1KHz
RMS = np.sqrt(np.sum(Power_Scaled_dB**2) / n_fft) # n_fft=8192 #Ans:24.4

###### Additional RMS tryouts #####
# Method 1 : Based on PSD formula
Px = 10**(np.max(114/10)) # Ans: 251188643150.9
RMS_Px = np.sqrt(np.sum(Px**2) / n_fft) # Ans: 2775268639.5
RMS_Px_dB = 10*np.log10(RMS_Px) # Ans: 94

# Method 2: Based on amplitude fomrula
A = np.sqrt(Px) # Ans: 501187.2
RMS_A = A / np.sqrt(n_fft) # nfft= 8192(fft length), Ans: 5537.388930343294
RMS_A_dB = 20*np.log10(RMS_A) # Ans: 74
```

With a 114dB 1Hz Sine wave input signal, after stft i obtain the psd in the plot [image]

Now I want to derive the PSD from the spectrum, to further calculate the average/RMS of the spectrum. Given by the relation PSD and from there I want to calculate RMS given by the relation RMS/Leq. I am unsure how to derive the PSD from the Power_avg

[image: PSD] and [image: RMS]

Answer (score 1):

By [Welch's method](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/sasp/Welch_s_Method.html), you can calculate the power spectrum by averaging the magnitude of a bunch of FFT frames (or time frames of the STFT). If your signal is $x(t)$, and its STFT is $X(\omega, \tau)$, where $\omega$ is the frequency bin, $\tau$ is the time frame and $T$ is the total number of frames, the PSD is

$$P_x(\omega) = \frac{1}{T} \sum_{\tau=0}^{T-1} |X(\omega, \tau)|^2 $$

When calculating the STFT, you need to make sure you get constant overlap add. This means, with the Hann window, you need a hopSize of N/2 (where N is your window length). I'd also keep the window length shorter, about 256/512 samples. This is not compulsory in your case, because your signal is stationary. Had it not been stationary you should have chosen a smaller window length. Here is your code, modified.

```
    y, sr = librosa.load('Noise Recorder.wav',sr=None,duration=2) 
    n_fft = 8192
    win_len = 512
    S = librosa.stft(y=y,n_fft=n_fft,win_length=win_len,hop_length=win_len/2,window='hann')     # Short FFT
    F = librosa.fft_frequencies(sr=sr, n_fft=n_fft) # Frequency components
    Abs = np.abs(S)  # Same as mag, phase = librosa.magphase(S)
    
    PSD = np.mean(Abs**2, axis=1).  #this is the power spectrum
    PSD_dB = 10*np.log10(PSD). #power spectrum in dB
    RMS = np.sqrt(np.mean(PSD**2))) #RMS of the power spectrum
    RMS_dB = 20*np.log10(RMS) # RMS of power spectrum in dB

    ##Theoretical RMS (in dB) for a sine wave of amplitude A dB
    A_lin = 10**(A/20.0)           #convert dB to linear amplitude, A = 114 in your case
    RMS_exp = 20*np.log10(A_lin/n_fft)   #expected RMS in dB
```

`

Comment: Thanks. Just for clarity, here the T represents the number of time frames and not the total duration of the time. I cover 12-time frames covering a total duration of 2S. one more question, how can I obtain the single value RMS/power average in the frequency domain. Is it just the max of the power spectrum?

Comment: From the relation, after interchanging the last 2 lines, the ```Power_avg``` would be the PSD?

Comment: Yes, T represents the total number of time frames, I have edited to answer tor reflect that. As for obtaining a single value, the PSD is usually defined over the frequency axis. The RMS of the spectrum would be $\sqrt{\frac{1}{Nfft} \sum_{\omega=0}^{Nfft-1} P_x(\omega)^2}$, i.e, the square root of the mean of the squared values in $P_x$.

Comment: $Nfft$ is the total number of frequency bins, or size of the FFT

Comment: Thanks @Orchisama, I have added the ```RMS``` formula in the question and also changed the plot. PSD showing a Sine wave at 114dB 1Hz. I think the rms/power average should give me 114dB, but with the calculation i get 24dB. Can you please check, what i am missing here?

Comment: Did you mean 1kHz? Because that is where the peak is.  You can see that the amplitude is correct in the PSD plot, l see a value of 114dB, which is good. Not sure where the two other peaks are coming from. 
Theoretically, for a sine wave of amplitude $A$, the RMS of the PSD should be  $\frac{A}{\sqrt{Nfft}}$. What is this value for you? 24dB could come from here, but the other spurious peaks are likely to mess things up. Also please convert to dB after doing all other calculations.

Comment: Yes, the peak is correct at the graph at 1KHz 114dB. Here i have a confusion with NFFT at the formula, Is ```Nfft=8192 #FFT length``` or ```Nfft=4097 #(1+8192/2)``` or ```Nfft=6 #Hz resolution```. I calculated RMS based on the formula "the square root of the mean of the squared values in Px" in the non dB unit as you mentioned. I also did a simple RMS for a single peak 114 dB for comparison with both formulas and modified the question with the program. @Orchisama Can you please check here which one is preferred for the calculation?